# Use tmux set-clipboard in gnome-terminal (XTerm's disallowedWindowOps)

Tags: gnome-terminal, clipboard, xterm, tmux

As shown in the [manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tmux.1.html) tmux supports the `set-clipboard` option to control the system clipboard using the terminal escape codes `\e]52;...\007`. I would like to use this functionality in gnome-terminal, but I cannot figure out how to enable it. The manpage says the following needs to be configured for XTerm:

`disallowedWindowOps: 20,21,SetXprop`

But this does not seem to work for gnome-terminal. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is the bug for OSC 52 support: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=795774

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, gnome-terminal doesn't support this.

The actual emulation is handled by the `vte` widget. In its source code, `src/caps.c` contains the table where matching/parsing the incoming escape sequences begins. `\e]` is called `OSC` here, and `OSC "52..."` is not defined here.