# Configure xfce4-terminal to recognize ANSI OSC 52 escape sequences to control the clipboard

Tags: clipboard, tmux, xfce4-terminal, ansi

tmux can put text into the system clipboard using **ANSI OSC (*Operating System Control*) 52** escape sequences, but the terminal emulator needs to recognize them. xfce4-terminal, out-of-the-box doesn't seem to recognize them. Would anybody know how to configure xfce4-terminal to recognize these OSC 52 sequences ?

I've read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621522/use-tmux-set-clipboard-in-gnome-terminal-xterms-disallowedwindowops/621646) that gnome-terminal can't recognize them, so I started to suspect that xfce4-terminal might not too, but couldn't find info anywhere about it.

I'm running Xubuntu 17.10 with xfce4-terminal 0.8.6.

Comment: You might want to [report a bug](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Xfce4-terminal&component=General&resolution=---&Bugzilla_remember=on&Bugzilla_restrictlogin=on&GoAheadAndLogIn=Log%20in) (I found nothing on [OSC](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=OSC))

Comment: it's based on vte though, so may have to be fixed upstream first: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=795774